# CSS: How to flow text around both left and right images

Tags: css

I know `float:left` will allow text to flow around an image floated on the left.

And `float:right` will allow text to flow around an image floated on the right.

Is there a way to flow text around **both a left and right image?**

[image]

Comment: Did you try to type _text between images html_?)

Comment: @The No, those words did not come to mind when I searched. I guess I was just too focused on the `float` part. But again...no harm intended, apologies.

Comment: Never mind. Good  luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just as you said. You need to have one image with `float:left` and another with `float:right`. If both are placed before the text, they will each be at their respective top corners, horizontally aligned.

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x200" style="float:left;">

<img src="http://placehold.it/100x200" style="float:right;">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur viverra diam finibus arcu dictum, sed condimentum neque eleifend. Nullam non lobortis leo, a sollicitudin ipsum. Pellentesque gravida aliquet eros, in imperdiet eros dictum eu. Aenean vel pharetra libero. Nam vel risus sit amet tortor fermentum venenatis. Aenean efficitur, ante ac semper porta, turpis nunc dignissim risus, sed ullamcorper dolor lacus a felis. Sed vel nulla imperdiet, luctus tellus sed, pharetra sem. Nullam vehicula elit eget urna lobortis, at porta nunc tempor. In gravida aliquet rutrum. Cras at lacus ac felis egestas aliquet. Aenean viverra eu mauris a fermentum. Donec pharetra nisl ex, sit amet sodales orci lobortis id. Nullam lobortis dictum pharetra. Cras pellentesque rhoncus magna a ultricies. Quisque et vehicula risus, in porttitor ex. Quisque aliquet blandit velit ut gravida.
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried with the text between the 2 images-which of course did not work! :)